Identify SWDI on this TSSOP20 MCU
I have Chinese drone with unknown TSSOP-20 MCU on it, the marking on top of MCU is removed but I found VDD pin 9 and pin 7 GND on it and it matches STM8AF6213 (which is unlikely) or Chinese version of STM32 CH32X035F7P6/CH32X033F8P6 but I cant find on CH32X035XXP6 datasheet where SWD pin is
